# No overload matches this call in react testing library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I am using React Testing Library. Whenever, I try to import a class into the testing file, it gives an error stating:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, PoorMansUnknown> & { onSave: (post: { fullName: string; title: string; body: string; createdAt: string; updatedAt: string; }) => void; } & RouteComponentProps<...>>): NewQuestion', gave the following error.
    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, PoorMansUnknown> & { onSave: (post: { fullName: string; title: string; body: string; createdAt: string; updatedAt: string; }) => void; } & RouteComponentProps<...>>': history, location, match, onSave
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, PoorMansUnknown> & { onSave: (post: { fullName: string; title: string; body: string; createdAt: string; updatedAt: string; }) => void; } & RouteComponentProps<...>, context?: any): NewQuestion', gave the following error.
```

The application is working absolutely fine and I am only having issues while writing the tests.

And my test file is this:

```
import Abc from './Abc'
import { render, cleanup, fireEvent } from "react-testing-library";
import React from 'react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

test (' Abc', ()=> {
const { getByPlaceholderText, getByText } = render(<NewQuestion />);})
```

I get an error in the last line on the "NewQuestion part".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can simplify this:

```
export default class NewQuestion extends React.Component < Props & RouteComponentProps > {
```

to be only:

```
export default class NewQuestion extends React.Component < Props > {
since props already includes the ReactRouter props.
```

The error you see is because you didn't provide the necessary props (you need the route props and onSave since you didn't put them as optional).

For route props I recommend using a Router wrapper (see here: https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router#__docusaurus), and for onSave just pass jest.fn() (then you can make assertions if it was called and with what parameters.)

Complete example:

```
import NewQuestion from './NewQuestion'
import React from 'react'
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history'
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import { LocationDisplay, App } from './app'

test('NewQuestion', () => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory()
  const { getByPlaceholderText, getByText } = render(
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route render={(props) => <NewQuestion {...props} onSave={jest.fn()}} /> />
    </Router>
  )
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This did not solve my error. My code of NewQuestion works absolutely fine. But there seems to be an issue with my test file when I try to import it and call it in my render. i.e const { getByPlaceholderText, getByText } = render(<NewQuestion />);})  (LAST LINE).  After removing RouteComponentProps, the error is now:

Comment: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<Props>): NewQuestion', gave the following error.
    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<Props>': history, location, match, onSave
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: Props, context?: any): NewQuestion', gave the following error.
    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<Props>': history, location, match, onSavets(2769)

Comment: What can I change in my existing code such that I don't get the error? I am new to React with typescript and the React testing library @Kaca992

Comment: you need to provide the props or make them optional. Can you post a snippet of your component used in your code? (where you say it is working)

Comment: I have provided the entire file. This is a blog kind of page. So If I click on a new question, it routes me to a new page which is "NewQuestion.tsx" and I enter everything in the inputbox and submit my post which goes into the database. Everything is working fine. But I am mainly getting confused in the testing part. @

Comment: The routing is in another file called App.tsx. However the handleSave is in the same file as the code above

<Route
                    exact
                    path="/new"
                    component={(props) => <NewQuestion {...props} onSave={this.handleSave}/>}/>

Comment: so here Route is providing RouteParameters part to NewQuestion (...props) and onSave you are providing. Thats why it is working

Comment: I provided a minimal working example in my edit. try that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206869/discussion-between-rebel-and-kaca992).

Comment: I have pasted the entire testing code provided by you, still the error persists in <NewQuestion onSave={jest.fn()} /> where it gives the same error message.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include Route. try it now

Comment: You solved my error. What does your test exactly do here? @kaca992

Comment: Just checks that your component renders. You can fake you initial route using create memory history if you use some route props, and also use jest.fn() to read with what parameters your component is called. This is just a basic setup that you can use to test all variants you need. Read this to reduce boilerplate and simplify testing: https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router#reducing-boilerplate

Answer (score -2):

Check your file suffix to make sure it is .tsx

Comment: Question has already an accepted answer and this is not helpful at all. It is just a basic precaution that you can state in the comments.